# How can I get Awesome WM to display GNOME wallpapers on tags 2-9?

Tags: awesome

For some reason, the Awesome WM has stopped displaying backgrounds (wallpapers) on workspaces (tags) 2-9. It didn't used to do this, but has started doing this for some reason on the default configuration, using the stock config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Awesome, and this hasn't been happening again in 14.04.